# AirPods Pro: clogged ears (Airplane Ear or Eardrum Suck effect) with noise cancellation turned on

Tags: audio, headphones, airpods

I have recently bought a pair of AirPods Pro and noticed a strange effect. It is difficult to explain, but it feels like a bit softer clogged ears (Airplane Ear) effect. The same like in the airplane or mountains when you move fast up or down. You naturally want to swallow in order to unclog ears and it helps for some time, but then the effect repeats. In transparency mode or with noise cancellation turned off everything feels normally, like generic in-ear headphones.

It is easier to notice this effect when sitting in the almost silent room with AirPods Pro turned on, but without music.

So the question is does anyone also experience the same? Maybe it is a common effect for in-ear headphones with noise cancellation and other brands are affected too? Or should I bring them to service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you are describing is commonly referred to as "eardrum suck". It's a common complaint for any type of noise-cancelling earphones.

Only some people are sensitive to it, and the stronger the noise-cancellation, the more likely it will bother you. Headphones seem more likely to cause it than earbuds.

According to Brent Butterworth, a headphone reviewer, it's an aural illusion caused by the nature of noise cancelling circuitry (there is no pressure on your eardrum, it just feels that way). It's a little difficult to explain succinctly, but this article goes into all the details: https://www.soundstagesolo.com/index.php/features/178-eardrum-suck-the-mystery-solved

Comment: Yes, it seems so, I’ve found a very similar explanation eventually, but thanks for putting the answer here and for the link!